# Jquery length of attribute undefined

Tags: jquery, attr

How can I check the lenght of the string that is in the attribute?This shows 'undefined' value:

`var action = $(obj).closest("form").attr('action');

alert(action.lenght);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your spelling is just a bit off, `.lenght` should be [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length):

```
var action = $(obj).closest("form").attr('action');
alert(action.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Always goto api when some method is not found before you make a post somewhere.

http://api.jquery.com

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: While this is good advice, it's also incorrect answer, the `.length` he wants is a **string** property (what `.attr()` returns in this case), he's not looking for the jQuery object `.length` property.