# jquery count characters on span tag

Tags: jquery

I may be missing something pretty obvious, but somehow I am struggling to count the characters inside a span tag.
The span is dynamically populated and I am trying to get its lenght, spaces included, to adjust the width of a column.
If I run only text() or html() I can get the content:

```
<span id="vlen00">someword</span>

vlenght = $('#vlen00').text();//vlenght is assigned 'someword'
vlenght = $('#vlen00').html();//this also gives me 'someword'
```

But when I tried to size it up like:

```
vlenght = $('#vlen00').text().lenght;//that gives me 'undefined'
vlenght = vlenght.lenght;//that also gives me 'undefined'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Was the misspelling of "length" on purpose? i.e. lenght. That will kinda be problematic.

Comment: **exact** duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376276/jquery-lenght-of-attribute-undefined lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change lenght to length.It will work

change

`vlenght = $('#vlen00').text().lenght;`  to

```
vlenght = $('#vlen00').text().length;
```

Comment: Shame on me! Late hours can take a toll on spelling.Thanks all.

Comment: Sorry PSR, besides misspelling I can also mistype.

Answer (score 0):

You have the name of the property wrong - it's `length` not `lenght`